# Can't build NotificationCompat.Builder in Android O

Tags: java, android

I have written an AAR library that implements some Android notification functionality. When I try to create a notification on devices running Android O (26+) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder' appears in /data/app/org.myapp-VuZkSUvRuAyiaIG5th_Mrw==/base.apk)
       at org.myapp.notificationutility.NotificationService.createNotification(NotificationService.java:208)
       at org.myapp.notificationutility.NotificationService.showNotification(NotificationService.java:169)
       at org.myapp.notificationutility.NotificationService.onStartCommand(NotificationService.java:117)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3668)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:200)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1682)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6680)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I made sure my code follows what is shown at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java

The exception happens at the `new NotificationCompat.Buider` line below. My code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String name = "My App";
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
        CHANNEL_ID,
        name,
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.CYAN);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
    .setContentText(notificationContent)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setOngoing(true);
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The error indicates that the `new NotificationCompat.Buider` constructor that takes a context and `String CHANNEL_ID` doesn't exist when running on device, but Android Studio builds the module without any errors. If Android Studio builds the AAR without errors (the method exists in the library at build), shouldn't the method exist at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the application you're using this library in is forcing a version of the support library that's older than 26.1.0, even though your library specifies that it requires 28.0.0 or above. You can verify this by running:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration releaseCompileClasspath --dependency support-compat
```

Which should show you the versions that are being brought in, and from where. Note that your configuration may vary if you have multiple `productFlavors` in your app configuration (e.g. if you have flavor "production" you would specify `--configuration productionReleaseCompileClasspath`).

Basically your library gets compiled with `support-compat` 28.+ (whatever that resolves to at the time -- I would highly recommend using a fixed version number instead), but when included in the application, the app configuration pulls in a different version of the `support-compat` library which your library is incompatible with. You'll need to update the app to ensure it's using `support-compat` 26.1.0 or later.